# Add non-pip package (ffmpeg) dependency in pipenv

Tags: ffmpeg, subprocess, pipenv, pipenv-install, pipfile

I have some python code that uses `subprocess` to run the following command (generates subtitles):

```
autosub interview.mp3
```

To make sure this works I have added `autosub` as a dependency in my Pipfile. Furthermore, this library is dependent on the [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) command line tool, which I have installed locally (`brew install ffmpeg`).

The problem: whenever I try running my code in the project pipenv environment, I get the error that `ffmpeg` cant be found.

Anyone know of a way to include the `ffmpeg` package in my project pipenv virtual environment?

Note: Ive already tried adding the `ffmpeg` in the project root folder but this doesnt solve the issue since `autosub` is running from the pipenv bin folder.